# elasticsearch aggregates some values in a single field

Tags: database, elasticsearch, aggregates

### I have some raw data

```
{
  {
    "id":1,
    "message":"intercept_log,UDP,0.0.0.0,68,255.255.255.255,67"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "message":"intercept_log,TCP,172.22.96.4,52085,239.255.255.250,3702,1:"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "message":"intercept_log,UDP,1.0.0.0,68,255.255.255.255,67"
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "message":"intercept_log,TCP,173.22.96.4,52085,239.255.255.250,3702,1:"
  }
}
```

#### Demand

I want to group this data by the value of the message part of the message.
Output value like that

```
{
  {
    "GroupValue":"TCP",
    "DocCount":"2"
  },
  {
    "GroupValue":"UDP",
    "DocCount":"2"
  }
}
```

#### Try

- I have tried with these codes but failed

```
GET systemevent*/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "message.keyword",
        "include": " intercept_log[,，](.*?)[,，].*?"
      }
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

- Now I try to use pipelines to meet this need.
- "aggs" seems to only group fields.
- Does anyone have a better idea?

#### Link

[Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

#### Update

My scene is a little special. I collect logs from many different servers, and then import the logs into es. Therefore, there is a big difference between message fields. If you directly use script statements for grouping statistics, it will result in group failure or inaccurate grouping. I try to filter out some data according to the conditions, and then use script to group the operation code (comment code 1), but this code can't group the correct results.

This is my scene to add:

Our team uses es to analyze the server log, uses rsyslog to forward the data to the server center, and then uses logstash to filter and extract the data to es. At this time, there is a field called message in ES, and the value of message is the detailed log information. At this time, we need to count the data containing some values in the message.

#### comment code 1

```
POST systemevent*/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": {
              "query": "intercept_log"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "protocol": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "def values = /,/.split(doc['message.keyword'].value); return values.length > 1 ? values[1] : 'N/A'",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

#### comment code 2

```
POST test2/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "protocol": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "def values = /.*,.*/.matcher( doc['host.keyword'].value ); if( name.matches() ) {return values.group(1) } else { return 'N/A' }",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is by leveraging scripts in the `terms` aggregation. The script would simply split on commas and take the second value.

```
    POST systemevent*/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "protocol": {
          "terms": {
            "script": "def values = /,/.split(doc['message.keyword'].value); return values.length > 1 ? values[1] : 'N/A';",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Use Regex

```
POST test2/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "protocol": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "def m = /.*proto='(.*?)'./.matcher(doc['message.keyword'].value ); if( m.matches() ) { return m.group(1) } else { return 'N/A' }"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results would look like

```
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "TCP",
      "doc_count" : 2
    },
    {
      "key" : "UDP",
      "doc_count" : 2
    }
  ]
```

[image]

A better and more efficient way would be to split the `message` field into new fields using an ingest pipeline or Logstash.

Comment: This is cool ! Thanks for your answer. but if our message field doesn't have a regular value example "aabbb," we'll get a runtime error. How can I avoid it.

Comment: Since you're using Logstash, I'm wondering why you don't parse the message field before indexing the document into ES. Just forwarding heterogenous logs without qualifying them is not a really good approach. What I suggested in my answer (script based approach) should only be used sparingly, but if you have a way to better parse your data before it lands into ES, you should definitely do it.

Comment: We do not choose to change the logstash configuration file because we only have one logstash deployment opportunity, and we have countless logstash to deploy, and after deployment, we cannot upgrade remotely. Therefore, we can only provide a general configuration file for logstash. So we can only filter on the ES side. I wonder if it is possible to aggregate using the regular in Scipt.

Comment: In Logstash you can definitely have several configurations without having multiple instances. It's called [pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html) and each application can have its own pipeline. If you have a large diversity of logs flowing into Logstash/ES, it makes no sense to let ES do all the job by streaming heterogeneous raw data into ES.

Comment: Please let me introduce that I am engaged in the railway industry. We need to collect the data of station equipment. These stations are distributed in every corner of our country. They may be in the desert and the virgin forest. The staff there have no computer concept. They can not provide the data of the station. Let us configure the exclusive logstash. It takes a long time for developers to go back and forth to a station, which will make it difficult for us to complete our data collection plan.

Comment: Can I get the data I want by modifying 'comment code 2' (local in describe)

Comment: In this case, I guess that each station should simply have a [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/index.html) instance deployed that sends all the raw logs to a centralized Logstash instance that is under the control of developers. Believe me, if you have that many stations reporting data, the last thing you want is that they all report their own raw unprocessed data into ES. If you don't control what is going to land into ES, you're going to have a very hard time leveraging your data.

Comment: We need to make statistical analysis on some values in the message field. If we use logstash to parse and copy to es, the data in our table will become confusing and difficult to understand. If multiple indexes are established, it will lead to index management problems, and ES parallel analysis is not recommended.

Comment: I obviously don't know enough about your use case. So go ahead with your scripted aggregation and at some point in the future, once you start seeing the shortcomings of this approach, we can pick up from here and talk further :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis and suggestions. We can continue to discuss it in the near future

Comment: I've found a way to use regex. Thanks for your help!